# Is it possible to make \flushbottom more flexible?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, glue

When I use `\flushbottom`, I get good results most of the time, but it is not uncommon that in order to align the last line of text with the bottom of the sheet's text area, Latex has to stretch the vertical spaces.
Consider the example below (MWE below), the situation is deliberately exaggerated just to illustrate the problem :

[image]

The vertical space before and after the word "TEST" should be between 9 and 11 pt (`\vspace{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}`), but it clearly is not. The space is stretched beyond the range of allowed values, and there are large blanks before and after the word "TEST", which I think is very unattractive.

I know that to avoid such situations (without using `\raggedbottom` for the whole document), one can play with `\enlargethispage` or `\looseness`, but it is not always sufficient and aesthetically unsatisfactory.

Hence my question:

***Is it possible to make the behaviour of `\flushbottom` more flexible?***

More precisely, is it possible to modify `\flushbottom` so that :

1. Latex tries to align the last line with the bottom of the page
   (default behaviour which works in most cases)
2. if impossible to do so (i.e. by not respecting the finite
   values of the vertical glues: here vertical spaces between 9 and
   11 pt, **no more, no less**), never mind, `\raggedbottom` is used for these
   particular pages (actually `\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ \@plus.0001fil}`).

I did some research about it and found nothing, I doubt it is possible to program.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\widowpenalties 1 10000 %deliberately exaggerated
\newcommand{\test}{%
    \vspace{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
    TEST%
    \vspace{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
}
\flushbottom
% \raggedbottom
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus. Donec in maximus leo. Phasellus eu sem dapibus, laoreet risus nec, eleifend ex. Sed id laoreet magna. Phasellus sit amet ultricies sem. Phasellus id felis viverra, porttitor enim vitae, accumsan nisi. Aenean ex tortor, elementum a placerat at, vulputate at ligula. Donec sagittis lacus ut elementum venenatis. Aliquam rhoncus feugiat egestas. In dapibus urna sed vulputate accumsan. Duis sit amet metus metus. Ut risus urna, blandit ac diam in, sodales tempus arcu. Nullam sed gravida justo, non auctor ex. Maecenas ac egestas velit, vitae fringilla sem. Cras quis justo orci. In maximus rhoncus lectus, sed tincidunt neque efficitur finibus. In sit amet gravida neque. Mauris egestas nec neque in finibus. Nulla venenatis sagittis mauris, vitae placerat quam scelerisque imperdiet. Nulla ullamcorper sem ut dolor eleifend, in pellentesque justo eleifend. Donec euismod sed leo sed venenatis. Nam vestibulum euismod ante id faucibus. Vestibulum vestibulum enim tortor, a eleifend nisi aliquam nec. Nulla sem ipsum, varius vel volutpat nec, condimentum id diam. Aenean vehicula libero vel turpis tristique, vitae pharetra erat luctus. Sed finibus libero ac velit scelerisque, a hendrerit dui bibendum. Cras in urna dolor. Donec cursus ultricies sapien ut iaculis. Suspendisse iaculis congue nisi, sit amet condimentum nunc venenatis nec. Sed vitae tellus tempus, feugiat purus vitae, aliquam est. Mauris mattis ante vel felis mattis, quis gravida felis facilisis. Sed eu purus quis nunc porttitor euismod. Sed quis efficitur quam. Mauris vulputate massa vitae libero tincidunt, sit amet condimentum tortor dapibus. Ut sed arcu accumsan tellus vehicula tincidunt in nec ante. Mauris in sagittis odio. Curabitur quis turpis ac felis hendrerit tincidunt et eu tortor.

\test

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\advance\baselineskip by 0pt plus 1pt}` has an interesting effect.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, this is interesting, but to be used sparingly. I don't think you should exceed a stretch of 0.5 pt (or even less), but this low value multiplied by the number of lines (in this case about forty) on the page, you get a significant total stretch value.

Comment: It's like wanting to swim and watch the clothes. If you want the trick of stretching vertical spaces to be less noticeable, use it extensively or don't use it at all. The issue is not that stretch too much, but that you left there too much bottom space and too few places to distribute it. IMHO the solution is not to prevent \flushbottom from work at full capacity, but to let it do it well.  The flexibility is a good idea, but in any vertical space that you can use (paragraph and captions  skips, etc.) and in page breaks (judicious use of floats, tolerance  widows and orphans,etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask to `\badness` value in the output routine when `\pagebody` is created. If the badness is greater than 100 then the stretching is bigger than allowed by numbers in `plus <something>` specification.

In plain TeX (where the output routine is simple) it can be implemented by:

```
\def\pagebody{\setbox0=\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}
   \ifnum\badness>100 \setbox0=\vbox to\vsize{\unvbox0\vfil}
                      \message{leaving blank bottom}\else
                      \message{keeping last line position}\fi
   \box0
}

% test:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus. Donec in maximus leo. Phasellus eu sem dapibus, laoreet risus nec, eleifend ex. Sed id laoreet magna. Phasellus sit amet ultricies sem. Phasellus id felis viverra, porttitor enim vitae, accumsan nisi. Aenean ex tortor, elementum a placerat at, vulputate at ligula. Donec sagittis lacus ut elementum venenatis. Aliquam rhoncus feugiat egestas. In dapibus urna sed vulputate accumsan. Duis sit amet metus metus. Ut risus urna, blandit ac diam in, sodales tempus arcu. Nullam sed gravida justo, non auctor ex. Maecenas ac egestas velit, vitae fringilla sem. Cras quis justo orci. In maximus rhoncus lectus, sed tincidunt neque efficitur finibus. In sit amet gravida neque. Mauris egestas nec neque in finibus. Nulla venenatis sagittis mauris, vitae placerat quam scelerisque imperdiet. Nulla ullamcorper sem ut dolor eleifend, in pellentesque justo eleifend. Donec euismod sed leo sed venenatis. Nam vestibulum euismod ante id faucibus. Vestibulum vestibulum enim tortor, a eleifend nisi aliquam nec. Nulla sem ipsum, varius vel volutpat nec, condimentum id diam. Aenean vehicula libero vel turpis tristique, vitae pharetra erat luctus. Sed finibus libero ac velit scelerisque, a hendrerit dui bibendum. Cras in urna dolor. Donec cursus ultricies sapien ut iaculis. Suspendisse iaculis congue nisi, sit amet condimentum nunc venenatis nec. Sed vitae tellus tempus, feugiat purus vitae, aliquam est. Mauris mattis ante vel felis mattis, quis gravida felis facilisis. Sed eu purus quis nunc porttitor euismod. Sed quis efficitur quam. Mauris vulputate massa vitae libero tincidunt, sit amet condimentum tortor dapibus. Ut sed arcu accumsan tellus vehicula tincidunt in nec ante. Mauris in sagittis odio. Curabitur quis turpis ac felis hendrerit tincidunt et eu tortor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringil

% a barrier in the page contents:
\hbox{\vrule height10cm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringil

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringil

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus. Donec in maximus leo. Phasellus eu sem dapibus, laoreet risus nec, eleifend ex. Sed id laoreet magna. Phasellus sit amet ultricies sem. Phasellus id felis viverra, porttitor enim vitae, accumsan nisi. Aenean ex tortor, elementum a placerat at, vulputate at ligula. Donec sagittis lacus ut elementum venenatis. Aliquam rhoncus feugiat egestas. In dapibus urna sed vulputate accumsan. Duis sit amet metus metus. Ut risus urna, blandit ac diam in, sodales tempus arcu. Nullam sed gravida justo, non auctor ex. Maecenas ac egestas velit, vitae fringilla sem. Cras quis justo orci. In maximus rhoncus lectus, sed tincidunt neque efficitur finibus. In sit amet gravida neque. Mauris egestas nec neque in finibus. Nulla venenatis sagittis mauris, vitae placerat quam scelerisque imperdiet. Nulla ullamcorper sem ut dolor eleifend, in pellentesque justo eleifend. Donec euismod sed leo sed venenatis. Nam vestibulum euismod ante id faucibus. Vestibulum vestibulum enim tortor, a eleifend nisi aliquam nec. Nulla sem ipsum, varius vel volutpat nec, condimentum id diam. Aenean vehicula libero vel turpis tristique, vitae pharetra erat luctus. Sed finibus libero ac velit scelerisque, a hendrerit dui bibendum. Cras in urna dolor. Donec cursus ultricies sapien ut iaculis. Suspendisse iaculis congue nisi, sit amet condimentum nunc venenatis nec. Sed vitae tellus tempus, feugiat purus vitae, aliquam est. Mauris mattis ante vel felis mattis, quis gravida felis facilisis. Sed eu purus quis nunc porttitor euismod. Sed quis efficitur quam. Mauris vulputate massa vitae libero tincidunt, sit amet condimentum tortor dapibus. Ut sed arcu accumsan tellus vehicula tincidunt in nec ante. Mauris in sagittis odio. Curabitur quis turpis ac felis hendrerit tincidunt et eu tortor.

\bye
```

Try to run this by `pdftex test`.

In OpTeX, the idea is similar, but its \output routine uses different vocabulary:

```
\_def\_completepage{\_vbox{%
         \_resetcolor
         \_istoksempty \_pgbackground
            \_iffalse \_backgroundbox{\_the\_pgbackground}\_nointerlineskip \_fi
         \_makeheadline
         \setbox0=\_vbox to\_vsize {\_boxmaxdepth=\_maxdepth \_pagecontents}%   
         \ifnum\badness>100 \setbox0=\vbox to\vsize{\unvbox0\vfil}
                          \message{leaving blank bottom}\else
                          \message{keeping last line position}\fi
         \box0
         \_makefootline}%
    }
     
% test:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus. Donec in maximus leo. Phasellus eu sem dapibus, laoreet risus nec, eleifend ex. Sed id laoreet magna. Phasellus sit amet ultricies sem. Phasellus id felis viverra, porttitor enim vitae, accumsan nisi. Aenean ex tortor, elementum a placerat at, vulputate at ligula. Donec sagittis lacus ut elementum venenatis. Aliquam rhoncus feugiat egestas. In dapibus urna sed vulputate accumsan. Duis sit amet metus metus. Ut risus urna, blandit ac diam in, sodales tempus arcu. Nullam sed gravida justo, non auctor ex. Maecenas ac egestas velit, vitae fringilla sem. Cras quis justo orci. In maximus rhoncus lectus, sed tincidunt neque efficitur finibus. In sit amet gravida neque. Mauris egestas nec neque in finibus. Nulla venenatis sagittis mauris, vitae placerat quam scelerisque imperdiet. Nulla ullamcorper sem ut dolor eleifend, in pellentesque justo eleifend. Donec euismod sed leo sed venenatis. Nam vestibulum euismod ante id faucibus. Vestibulum vestibulum enim tortor, a eleifend nisi aliquam nec. Nulla sem ipsum, varius vel volutpat nec, condimentum id diam. Aenean vehicula libero vel turpis tristique, vitae pharetra erat luctus. Sed finibus libero ac velit scelerisque, a hendrerit dui bibendum. Cras in urna dolor. Donec cursus ultricies sapien ut iaculis. Suspendisse iaculis congue nisi, sit amet condimentum nunc venenatis nec. Sed vitae tellus tempus, feugiat purus vitae, aliquam est. Mauris mattis ante vel felis mattis, quis gravida felis facilisis. Sed eu purus quis nunc porttitor euismod. Sed quis efficitur quam. Mauris vulputate massa vitae libero tincidunt, sit amet condimentum tortor dapibus. Ut sed arcu accumsan tellus vehicula tincidunt in nec ante. Mauris in sagittis odio. Curabitur quis turpis ac felis hendrerit tincidunt et eu tortor.

% barrierr:
\hbox{\vrule height11cm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus. Donec in maximus leo. Phasellus eu sem dapibus, laoreet risus nec, eleifend ex. Sed id laoreet magna. Phasellus sit amet ultricies sem. Phasellus id felis viverra, porttitor enim vitae, accumsan nisi. Aenean ex tortor, elementum a placerat at, vulputate at ligula. Donec sagittis lacus ut elementum venenatis. Aliquam rhoncus feugiat egestas. In dapibus urna sed vulputate accumsan. Duis sit amet metus metus. Ut risus urna, blandit ac diam in, sodales tempus arcu. Nullam sed gravida justo, non auctor ex. Maecenas ac egestas velit, vitae fringilla sem. Cras quis justo orci. In maximus rhoncus lectus, sed tincidunt neque efficitur finibus. In sit amet gravida neque. Mauris egestas nec neque in finibus. Nulla venenatis sagittis mauris, vitae placerat quam scelerisque imperdiet. Nulla ullamcorper sem ut dolor eleifend, in pellentesque justo eleifend. Donec euismod sed leo sed venenatis. Nam vestibulum euismod ante id faucibus. Vestibulum vestibulum enim tortor, a eleifend nisi aliquam nec. Nulla sem ipsum, varius vel volutpat nec, condimentum id diam. Aenean vehicula libero vel turpis tristique, vitae pharetra erat luctus. Sed finibus libero ac velit scelerisque, a hendrerit dui bibendum. Cras in urna dolor. Donec cursus ultricies sapien ut iaculis. Suspendisse iaculis congue nisi, sit amet condimentum nunc venenatis nec. Sed vitae tellus tempus, feugiat purus vitae, aliquam est. Mauris mattis ante vel felis mattis, quis gravida felis facilisis. Sed eu purus quis nunc porttitor euismod. Sed quis efficitur quam. Mauris vulputate massa vitae libero tincidunt, sit amet condimentum tortor dapibus. Ut sed arcu accumsan tellus vehicula tincidunt in nec ante. Mauris in sagittis odio. Curabitur quis turpis ac felis hendrerit tincidunt et eu tortor.

\bye
```

Comment: Hello wipet, thank you for your answer, but how to adapt it to be used with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: @BLegrand You can combine my idea which works in plain TeX or OpTeX with the answer by David C. here. He show what to do In LaTeX. You can only replace his \ifdim condition by my \ifnum and surrounding code. I hope that it will work. I am not supporting LaTeX.

Comment: I tried `\def\@texttop{%
    \setbox0\vbox{\unvcopy\@outputbox}%
    \ifnum\badness>100%
        \typeout{Using raggedbottom on page \thepage}%
        \typeout{\the\dimexpr\@colht-\ht0>40pt}%
        \typeout{Badness : \the\badness}
        \def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ \@plus.0001fil}%
    \else%
        \typeout{Using flushbottom on page \thepage}%
        \typeout{Badness : \the\badness}
        \def\@textbottom{}%
    \fi%
}` but without succes `:/`.

Comment: @BLegrand The point is in the fact that you must to try to set the vbox to desired height in order to measure badness. So, use `\setbox0\vbox to\vsize{\unvcopy\@outputbox}`.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you ask for but this modifies things so at the start of the output it measures the natural height of the content, and if that is within 40pt of the desired size it uses flushbottom, otherwise it uses ragged

[image]

The terminal and log reports

```
Using raggedbottom on page 1
46.47656pt>40pt

Using flushbottom on page 2
6.47656pt<=40pt

Using raggedbottom on page 3
426.47656pt>40pt
```

With your example modified to be

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\widowpenalties 1 10000 %deliberately exaggerated
\newcommand{\test}{%
    \vspace{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
    TEST%
    \vspace{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
}
\flushbottom
\makeatletter
  \def\@texttop{%
  \setbox0\vbox{\unvcopy\@outputbox}% use 255 instead of \@outputbox in old formats
  \ifdim\dimexpr\@colht-\ht0
                  > 40pt % arbitrary value at which switch 
    \typeout{Using raggedbottom on page \thepage}%
    \typeout{\the\dimexpr\@colht-\ht0>40pt}%
    \def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ \@plus.0001fil}%
   \else
    \typeout{Using flushbottom on page \thepage}%
    \typeout{\the\dimexpr\@colht-\ht0<=40pt}%
    \def\@textbottom{}%
   \fi}

 \def\@textbottom{\vskip 0pt plus 1pt}
\makeatletter

% \raggedbottom
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus. Donec in maximus leo. Phasellus eu sem dapibus, laoreet risus nec, eleifend ex. Sed id laoreet magna. Phasellus sit amet ultricies sem. Phasellus id felis viverra, porttitor enim vitae, accumsan nisi. Aenean ex tortor, elementum a placerat at, vulputate at ligula. Donec sagittis lacus ut elementum venenatis. Aliquam rhoncus feugiat egestas. In dapibus urna sed vulputate accumsan. Duis sit amet metus metus. Ut risus urna, blandit ac diam in, sodales tempus arcu. Nullam sed gravida justo, non auctor ex. Maecenas ac egestas velit, vitae fringilla sem. Cras quis justo orci. In maximus rhoncus lectus, sed tincidunt neque efficitur finibus. In sit amet gravida neque. Mauris egestas nec neque in finibus. Nulla venenatis sagittis mauris, vitae placerat quam scelerisque imperdiet. Nulla ullamcorper sem ut dolor eleifend, in pellentesque justo eleifend. Donec euismod sed leo sed venenatis. Nam vestibulum euismod ante id faucibus. Vestibulum vestibulum enim tortor, a eleifend nisi aliquam nec. Nulla sem ipsum, varius vel volutpat nec, condimentum id diam. Aenean vehicula libero vel turpis tristique, vitae pharetra erat luctus. Sed finibus libero ac velit scelerisque, a hendrerit dui bibendum. Cras in urna dolor. Donec cursus ultricies sapien ut iaculis. Suspendisse iaculis congue nisi, sit amet condimentum nunc venenatis nec. Sed vitae tellus tempus, feugiat purus vitae, aliquam est. Mauris mattis ante vel felis mattis, quis gravida felis facilisis. Sed eu purus quis nunc porttitor euismod. Sed quis efficitur quam. Mauris vulputate massa vitae libero tincidunt, sit amet condimentum tortor dapibus. Ut sed arcu accumsan tellus vehicula tincidunt in nec ante. Mauris in sagittis odio. Curabitur quis turpis ac felis hendrerit tincidunt et eu tortor.

\test

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna.

\def\zz{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus turpis, fringilla sit amet ullamcorper id, auctor vitae libero. Donec quam leo, congue nec nibh at, accumsan pharetra ex. Proin scelerisque vestibulum vulputate. Fusce imperdiet rhoncus lectus, et semper urna. Morbi euismod interdum nisi ut iaculis. Phasellus elementum nisi et augue molestie varius. Praesent bibendum diam at ligula iaculis pharetra. Aliquam sem urna, maximus ac ante vel, finibus dignissim nisi. Quisque massa nisl, commodo ut porta non, placerat molestie dui. Vivamus sit amet purus nunc. Vestibulum viverra pharetra felis quis aliquam. Duis hendrerit laoreet nulla eget tristique. Maecenas ante eros, condimentum nec euismod consequat, venenatis nec dolor. Suspendisse ut dolor sapien. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam mattis nibh porttitor ipsum eleifend fringilla. Sed vulputate efficitur lorem et consectetur. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat elit, in scelerisque enim. Donec porta dictum leo ac condimentum. Pellentesque ac accumsan felis. Sed egestas eleifend turpis non fermentum. Etiam nisi nunc, pellentesque ac nunc a, lobortis lobortis leo. Sed vestibulum, arcu id ullamcorper varius, lacus tortor venenatis mi, ac euismod libero sem eget sem. Mauris quam dolor, cursus et ex et, tincidunt aliquet velit. Curabitur condimentum elementum arcu id efficitur. Phasellus hendrerit nulla nec nibh dictum consequat. Cras eget turpis nulla. Donec metus urna, elementum non turpis vitae, tempus tincidunt libero. Nam augue sapien, venenatis vulputate risus sit amet, scelerisque mollis neque. Nam eu diam libero. Vivamus vestibulum, tellus suscipit vulputate lobortis, dolor nunc dictum est, vel imperdiet nisl dolor in purus}

\zz


\widowpenalties0

\zz

\zz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, the approach is very interesting, I would not have thought of that! The calculation is made from the natural height of the page, but is it possible to access the shrinkage and stretching values of the glues that make up the page? So, for this example, we would know that the content of the page could be stretched by a maximum of 2 pt. To be honest, I don't know how the layout algorithm works.